# Creating objects containing objects from a list in java and not allowing the same obecjt to be used twice

Tags: java, list, arraylist, duplicates

Struggling to word this one but I have a list of players in a league. A league has a list of rounds, which has a list of games. I need to create games using two players from the list of players in the league

How can i ensure that when I create a game it does not use a player that has already been selected, as they are selected randomly from the list.

If i remove them from the list once they are selected then they  are removed from the league, which I do not want. If I copy the list of players (and remove from that) then the ones being used to create the games are not the original player objects

```
 public Player(int Id, String eMail, String forename, String lastname,League league) {
    this.msaId = Id;
    this.eMail = eMail;
    this.firstName = forename;
    this.lastName = lastname;
    this.league = league;
}

   public League(int Id, String leagueName, List<Player> players, List<Round> rounds, int numberOfPlayers, Tournament t) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.name = leagueName;
    this.players = players;
    this.rounds = rounds;
    this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    this.tournament = t;
}

  public Round(int Id, int numberOfPlayers, int roundNumber, League league) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.roundType = roundType;
    this.roundNumber = roundNumber;
    this.league = league;
    this.currentRound = false;
    this.roundStarted = false;
}
    public Game(int Id, int gameNumber, int roundId, Player playerOne, Player playerTwo, int tableNumber, Round r) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.gameNumber = gameNumber;
    this.roundId = roundId;
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
    this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
    this.playerOneScore = 0;
    this.playerTwoScore = 0;
    this.round = r;
}
```

Comment: We can't really help without seeing your player class, the the lists dealing with them. In general, one of your problems seems to be proper modelling: you see, it should really not matter to your player objects if they are in one, two, or twelve million lists. Each "player object" represents exactly one human being, and I guess you would agree: for that human being, it doesn't really matter if his names shows up in one, two or 5 different phone books. That one human being is still the same single person.

Comment: Ive added my classes involved

Comment: You could add an attribute to the `Player` class, isSelected as a `boolean` and when you use the random selection and the player.isSelected is true, pick another `Player`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an ArrayList with a List of players by that round.
I am going to try to explain better myself with a piece of code.

```
private List<Player> leaguePlayers;
private Map<Round, List<Player>> playersByRound;
```

With this structure before to add a player to one Round, you can verify if the new player to add is into the list like this.

```
public boolean checkIsSelectablePlayerByRound(Player player, Round round){
    for(Game game : gamesByRound.get(round)){
        if(game.playerOne == player || game.playerTwo == player){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: So for each round you would add a list of players, duplicating the list?

Comment: @user2190867 for each round i would add all players who play some game, would be a reference to the original object, no need to duplicate, you only need have the reference of what players played on what round. If i understand wrongly please let me know

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand.

My problem is that a game uses two players from the league. Similar to the premier league. How can I pair them all randomly, ensuring that one has not already been chosen for another game?

Comment: then to clarify you have a list of players, with all league players, and every game is a random selection of 11 players for each team right?

Comment: No sorry,my premier league example may have confused you. It is actually for creating a chess tournament. So a game is 1 v 1

Comment: Oks no problem. Then you could do something as i my example, here the steps: 1. select on player randomly from the league list; 2. check with the method if is a selectable player; 3. if its, add to the game or create a new game and add to the map